# Error: "invalid number of arguments in "uwsgi_param" directive" on nginx restart

Tags: nginx, centos6, django, uwsgi

CentOS 6.6, nginx 1.0.15.

I'm trying to configure nginx <-> uwsgi <-> Django stack, using this [tutorial](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html). The nginx conf file is:

```
upstream django {
    server 127.0.0.1:8001;
}

server {
    listen      8000;
    server_name 0.0.0.0; # an IP address of my server here
    charset     utf-8;
    client_max_body_size 75M;

    location /media  {
        alias /projects/myproject/media;
    }

    location /static {
        alias /projects/myproject/static;
    }

    location / {
        uwsgi_pass  django;
        include     /projects/myproject/uwsgi_params;
    }
}
```

The uwsgi_params file is:

```
uwsgi_param  QUERY_STRING       $query_string;
uwsgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD     $request_method;
uwsgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE       $content_type;
uwsgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH     $content_length;

uwsgi_param  REQUEST_URI        $request_uri;
uwsgi_param  PATH_INFO          $document_uri;
uwsgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT      $document_root;
uwsgi_param  SERVER_PROTOCOL    $server_protocol;
uwsgi_param  REQUEST_SCHEME     $scheme;
uwsgi_param  HTTPS              $https if_not_empty;

uwsgi_param  REMOTE_ADDR        $remote_addr;
uwsgi_param  REMOTE_PORT        $remote_port;
uwsgi_param  SERVER_PORT        $server_port;
uwsgi_param  SERVER_NAME        $server_name;
```

And on trying to start nginx I get the error:

```
$ sudo service nginx restart
nginx: [emerg] invalid number of arguments in "uwsgi_param" directive in /projects/myproject/uwsgi_params:12
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

Looks like nginx is confused with line 12 of uwsgi_params file, which is (given the 1st line is blank) an HTTPS config.

How do I fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

nginx is complaining about this line:

```
uwsgi_param  HTTPS              $https if_not_empty;
```

The `if_not_empty` parameter was [added](http://nginx.org/r/uwsgi_param) in nginx 1.1.11, so your version of nginx is too old to use it.

Since you are on CentOS, you should run the latest stable nginx provided by [nginx.org's own CentOS repository](http://nginx.org/en/linux_packages.html#stable). Updating to the latest stable nginx via this method will resolve the problem.